# <div> briefly appears before fadeIn - jQuery

Tags: jquery, fadein

I have a problem trying to make a fadeIn work properly.
The main section of the site (which may contain images, text, etc, and it's the only section that changes when navigating the site; header and footer are static) enters with a fadeIn. I made it work with the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("div.main").css("display", "none");
$("div.main").fadeIn(2000);
});
</script>
```

And I also tried the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("div.main").css("visibility", "visible").hide().fadeIn(2000);
});
</script>
```

The problem with both is, when moving between sections, I get a quick glimpse of this main div before it disappears to enter, the second time, with the fadeIn.  Could this be 'normal' behavior, how can I fix it?

I appreciate any guidance.

*Edit:*

*I did try the "display:none" property on the stylesheet but then, instead of the glimpse of the main div, I get the footer just below the header until the main content fades in.  Plus, if some users have javascript disabled they wouldn't see any content at all.  I also tried "visibility:hidden" on the css but then the fadein just doesn't work.*

*Edit 2 [SOLVED]:*

*I finally made it work moving the "display:none" to the css and then, to solve the disabled-javascript predicament, I followed the suggestions from this post (http://greatwebguy.com/programming/css/writing-javascript-specific-css/).  Hope it's okay to post the link, in case someone else finds it useful.*

*Thank you both for your help :)*

Comment: Your footer is out of place because its positioning, I assume, depends on the visibility of the 'main' div, which you want hidden.  If you position your footer in a different way, it will work.  I updated my post with a demo site that keeps the footer at the bottom.  For non-javascript users, perhaps a <noscript> section that modifies the CSS for .main directly in the page will override an external style sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(document).ready() will execute when the DOM is completely ready.  This only happens when the 'div' has been loaded and, therefore, flashed to your screen.  You can ensure that this does not happen with an initial:

```
<div class="main" style="display:none">...</div>
```

or just add 'display:none' to your '.main' CSS definition.  This will be modified in your function with the fadeIn.

Here is a full working copy that solves your 'jumping' footer problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/U7gfn/

Comment: Thanks! Your link will come in handy.  However I'm still trying to figure out the disabled javascript issue, since the <noscript> tag will cause the site not to be xhtml-valid.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("div.main").css("display", "none");
```

This function call will only fire when document is ready. Try using CSS without JS to hide the element before the page is rendered.

Comment: I did try, but then the footer <div> appears out of place (right below the header) until the main content fades in.

Comment: What exactly did you try? Adding `style="visibility:hidden;"` to your tag?

Comment: "display:none;" on the stylesheet.  Also "visibility:hidden" but then the fadein does not work at all and the main div it's just empty space.